# Publish jpg file as a ScreenSaver via GPO

Tags: group-policy, windows

Is it possible to publish jpg file as ScreenSaver via GPO?

My Company wants to pulish it's Logo as ScreenSaver ( the logo is in jpg format )

Comment: You're asking to publish a static JPG as a screensaver? Wouldn't that actually be wallpaper, and if it's just an image displayed as a screensaver, wouldn't it defeat the purpose of being a screen saver?

Comment: A picture is not a screensaver. It may be possible to push out a 'slideshow' screensaver that is locked down to just display one image, however. That somewhat negates the point of a screensaver though.

Comment: Hi Bart & DJ, Thanks for your comment. User has kept lots of files & folder and shortcut on their desktop so the images or logo or any type of message in logo is not displayed properly  as well as i just want to display the logo or some message in form of jpg in ScreenSaver for 3 or 5 minutes & after that the Monitor will switch off. we don't have CRT monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [a good article](http://codegrue.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/implement-a-standard-photo-screen-saver-through-group-policy/) that explains this perfectly, using the "Photos" screensaver - three things are involved:

1. Copy the image to a special folder using a logon script (or group policy preferences, as tegbains pointed out)
2. Set the Photos screen saver via GPO
3. Set the photos path via registry/GPO

The logon script is fairly trivial, copying from a network share to somewhere on the local hard drive.

The group policy settings for screensavers are found under

> Policy > User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization

where you can set which screensaver you want (in this case, the Photos screensaver).

Then you need to set the photo path, and export the registry key

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Slideshow\Screensaver

for use in your group policy.

Comment: For step 1, you can instead use Group Policy Preferences to copy the file the special folder

Answer (score 0):

If WinXP screen savers can be used with Windows 7, then the 3D Flying Objects screensaver allowed us to select a user-defined image as a textured flag that wafted and waved around the desktop. A pleasing effect for a corporate logo.

1. Save desired file somewhere on user's HDD as a BMP (only works with BMP files)
2. Choose 3D Flying Objects as screensaver
3. Settings button for that screensaver
4. On Style drop-down, select Textured Flag and then choose the bmp file you saved